# How can I check the value returned by a validation function to pass along the metrics to Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-analytics

I use a system that captures visitors information via a form. I can't edit the code of the form validation scripts. I am trying to see if I can check upon clicking on the submit button, before the form submit sends the person to the response URL if the validation was passed.

The "submit" calls the function "formSubmit()", if validation is passed myFormIsValid() is returned. If not, then return false to the form.

Like this:

```
function formSubmit(elt) {
  if (!myFormIsValid()) {
    return false;
  }
```

I want to know if validation was passed before allowing the form to move forward and do something like setting a variable value so I can tell Google Analytics that the form was successfully submitted. Is there a way to setup a "listener" to the results of the formSubmit function before it is called? I can put the code on the header or footer and I can use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the `submit` before it reaches it's destination with an event handler.

[jQuery.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#MyForm").submit(function (e) {
        if (!$(this).valid()) {
          e.preventDefault(); // prevents the form from submitting.
          return;
        }

        // you can do things here or just let it continue submitting.
    });
});
```